# Private class variable not being set

Tags: c++, string

My program takes input from a user, and assigns it to a private string variable.  Later, I access the variable but it return an empty string.  Heres my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class object{
    private:
        string item;
    public:
        void set_object(){
            cout << "Enter object";
            cin >> item;
            cout << "Address: " << &item << endl;
        }
        string get_object(){
            cout << "New address: " << &item << endl;
            return item;
        }
};

int main(){
    object obj;
    obj.set_object();
    cout << "Object: " << obj.get_object() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this, i get the following output:

Enter object: *text*

Address: 0x7fff567fa8e0

New address: 0x7fff567fa890

Object:

Not sure whats up, so any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: It is not a good idea to have a variable the same name as the class.  Change one of the names and try again.

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/Di4qrkXIQb48AolT).

Comment: I cannot reproduce this either (Xcode 7, Mac OS X El Capitan, debug and release builds). Sorry to ask, but are you sure the output you added to the question is really from the exact program as in your question? Or is it from a similar version...? And what compiler do you use? What OS? Release or debug build?

Comment: I'm ssh'ed into a linux server, and compiling with gcc ver. 4.4.7, but at this point I think it might just be some stupid mistake on my part.  Time to get out the rubber duck I guess.

Comment: I can't reproduce with gcc ver. 4.8.1 provided by mingw-64